# the output of my Interpolation search is wrong, why?

Tags: java, interpolation

I have to write a Program which is called "Interpolation search". I came so far but now I am stuck and can´t find the error in my code.
The method split() makes a problem. This method should give me the index to split. I just typed the formula in this method. Now the big problem is, I every time get 1 as an output which is always the "leftBoundary". For example, I write in my terminal java Search 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 then I get every time 1. Why? what is wrong?

edit:
I was asked to explain what the split method does in Detail:
This method uses the formula (look at added picture) to determine where to split the (sorted) array and returns the corresponding index.
In the picture: v = wantedValue, l = leftBoundary, r = rightBoundary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qmlb.jpg)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Search {

    // This method uses the formula (look at added picture) to determine where to split the (sorted) array and returns the corresponding index.
    private static int split(int[] haystack, int needle, int left, int right) {
        if(haystack[right] == haystack[left]) {
            return left;
        }else {
        needle = left + ((needle - haystack[left]) / (haystack[right] - haystack[left])) * (right - left);
        return needle;
        }
    }
    private static int search(int[] haystack, int needle) {

        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[args.length];
        int leftBoundary = 1;
        int rightBoundary = array.length - 1;
        int wantedValue = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


        for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
           array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

         int splitAtIndex = split(array, wantedValue, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
         System.out.println(splitAtIndex);
    }
}
```

I tried to debug but with no success and also searched  here on stackoverflow. Many have question to interpolation search, but the answers are complex and unfortunately do not explain the exact problem I have

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in detail what your `split`method should do. Your description does not explain the criterion for calculating the index `split` should return. Are you maybe trying to implement binary search?

Comment: Hey, I edited my question.  The split method should find the Index where to split -> that is the difference between binary search and interpolation search

Comment: @Valerij You already wrote that "the split method should find the index where to split". That description does not explain how to calculate that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74760288/the-output-of-my-interpolation-search-is-wrong-why#comment131943208_74760288), by @user16320675, to your question, your initialization is wrong.

The first [command-line] argument is the value of `wantedValue`. The remaining [command-line] arguments are the elements of `array`.

Also, `leftBoundary` should be 0 (zero) and not 1 (one) since you probably want to search the whole array.

Consider the following code:

```java
public class Search {

    private static int split(int[] haystack, int needle, int left, int right) {
        if (haystack[right] == haystack[left]) {
            return left;
        }
        else {
            return (int) (left + ((double) (needle - haystack[left]) / (haystack[right] - haystack[left])) * (right - left));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[args.length - 1];
        int leftBoundary = 0;
        int rightBoundary = array.length - 1;
        int wantedValue = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            array[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        int splitAtIndex = split(array, wantedValue, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
        System.out.println(splitAtIndex);
    }
}
```

I removed the `import` statement since `Scanner` is not used. I also removed method `search` since it is never called.

If I run the above code using your example [command-line] arguments, i.e.

```
4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

then method `search` returns 3 — which is the index of the searched-for element in the array since 4 is the searched-for value and the array contains the numbers 1 to 6 (inclusive).

Of-course, the array being searched must be sorted.

Note that if the searched-for value is smaller than the first array element, i.e. the element at index 0 (zero), method `search` will return -1 (minus one) and if the searched-for value is greater than the last element in the array, method `search` will return the array length. Hence you can determine whether the searched-for value is not found in the array.

If the [command-line] arguments are:

```
4 1 2 3 5 6
```

then method `search` returns 2. Note that the searched-for value, i.e. 4, is **not** in the array.

It is probably also a good idea to check the parameters of method `search`, i.e. that `right` should **not** be less than `left` and that `haystack` contains at least one element.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. I found it difficult to understand when you wrote that line "array[i - 1]". Especially why i - 1. but now I understand it. But I would not to come to this alone

Comment: Perhaps you laughing but it was mind-blowing to me. I never thought that way